# stretching one texture over multiple quads

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

To texture map a single quad the following code works:

```
glBegin( GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f( 0,0 ) ;
  glVertex3f( -1,-1,0);

  glTexCoord2f(1,0);
  glVertex3f(  1,-1,0);

  glTexCoord2f(1,1);
  glVertex3f(  1, 1,0);

  glTexCoord2f(0,1);
  glVertex3f( -1, 1,0);
glEnd();
```

My question is, how can I map the following multiple quad with one texture. The for loop creates a 10x10 quad made by smaller quads of 2 unit edges, I want to stretch my texture from 1x1th quad to 10x10th quad:

```
void wall(int num)
{
int wallx;
int wally;
for(wallx=0;wallx<num;wallx++)
{
    for(wally=0;wally<num;wally++)
    {
    glPushMatrix();
        glBegin( GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f( -1 + wallx*2,-1+ wally*2,0 );           
        glVertex3f(  1+ wallx*2,-1+ wally*2,0 );             
        glVertex3f(  1+ wallx*2, 1+ wally*2,0 );             
        glVertex3f(  -1+ wallx*2, 1+ wally*2,0 );           
            glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do my eyes deceive me ? glBegin() and glEnd() ? Please don't use that, it's deprecated.

Comment: How can I do this without using glBegin and glEnd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about it, this is just about specifying the correct texture coordinate for each quad.

```
float unitx = 1.0f/(float)num;
float unity = 1.0f/(float)num;
for(wallx=0;wallx<num;wallx++)
{
    for(wally=0;wally<num;wally++)
    {
    glPushMatrix();
        glBegin( GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f( unitx * (float) wallx, unity * (float) wally );
        glVertex3f( -1 + wallx*2,-1+ wally*2,0 );    
        glTexCoord2f( unitx * (float) (wallx+1), unity * (float) wally );
        glVertex3f(  1+ wallx*2,-1+ wally*2,0 );             
        glTexCoord2f( unitx * (float) (wallx+1), unity * (float) (wally+1) );
        glVertex3f(  1+ wallx*2, 1+ wally*2,0 );             
        glTexCoord2f( unitx * (float) wallx, unity * (float) (wally+1) );
        glVertex3f(  -1+ wallx*2, 1+ wally*2,0 );           
            glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can probably tell from your first code snippet, texture coordinates are in the range 0-1, so 0,0 is one corner progressing to 1,1 diagonally opposite. The unit size of your quads is irrelevant, texture coordinates are in texture-space, not world space.

Therefore, you just need to calculate your texture coordinates as being 1/n, where n is the number of quads you're using to build up your large quad. In this case, the first one would have coords (0,0), (0,0.1), (0.1,0) and (0.1,0.1) for example. Simply calculate 1/n then use this value in your loops to calculate the coords for each of the small quads. If you used the coordinates (0,0) in one corner of a quad, and (10,10) in the diagonally opposite corner (with the right values on the other two) then you'd get your texture tiled 10 times across that quad.